# Create has_many relationships from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So if I have a two models like this:

```
#parent.rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :children
end

#children.rb
class Child < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :parent
end
```

How would you create a form that allows you to create multiple children in the form that creates the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoon[0] solves this problem quite nicely, and has a great example app.

Rolling on the back-end, throw `accepts_nested_attributes_for :children` on your `Parent` model, do some `fields_for` (or `simple_fields_for`) stuff in your form, and make sure you can assign the attributes by adding `children_attributes: [:name, :age]` to your `parent_params`.

[0] https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon